# Gulp: Passing multiple command line parameters to the same task

Tags: command-line, gulp, parameter-passing

Goal:
Build /src/assets/(theme)/*.scss by passing the parameter in the command line using flag --theme. I solved step one using gulp-utils

```
function sass() {
  // return gulp.src('/src/assets/scss/**/*.scss')
  return gulp.src(['src/assets/scss/' + (util.env.theme ? util.env.theme : 'app') + '.scss'])
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: PATHS.sass
    })
      .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: COMPATIBILITY
    }))
    // Comment in the pipe below to run UnCSS in production
    //.pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.uncss(UNCSS_OPTIONS)))
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.cleanCss({ compatibility: 'ie9' })))
    .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/css'))
    .pipe(browser.reload({ stream: true }));
}
```

**Remaining**:
`gulp build --production --theme folderName1, folderName2, folderName*`
Passing multiple theme values --theme folderName1 folderName2 to the same `sass()` function/task.

This would send folderName to function sass()

```
function sass() {
  // return gulp.src('/src/assets/scss/**/*.scss')
  return gulp.src([
     'src/assets/scss/folderName1/*.scss',
     'src/assets/scss/folderName2/*.scss',
     'src/assets/scss/folderName3/*.scss'
  ])
    ...

    ...
}
```

Would creating an argsList like this SitePoint [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/pass-parameters-gulp-tasks/#howtopassargumentstoyourgulpjstasks) discusses work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues was able to help resolve this issue. Instead of using gulp.utils he was able to use yargs.argv.theme with slipt(,). This allows for a user to pass the --theme param and pass as many comma-separated items as desired.

```
  function sass() {
  if (yargs.argv.theme) {
    let collection = yargs.argv.theme.split(','),
      results = collection.map(item =>  `./src/assets/scss/${item}/*.scss`);

    return gulp.src(results)
      .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe($.sass({
        includePaths: PATHS.sass
      })
        .on('error', $.sass.logError))
      .pipe($.autoprefixer({
        browsers: COMPATIBILITY
      }))
      // Comment in the pipe below to run UnCSS in production
      //.pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.uncss(UNCSS_OPTIONS)))
      .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.cleanCss({ compatibility: 'ie9' })))
      .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.write()))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/css'))
      .pipe(browser.reload({ stream: true }));
  }
}
```

Comment: For a couple of other ideas for passing multiple parameters see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315191/send-arguments-to-gulp-task/46315740#46315740

Answer (score 0):

Please review your idea. This package looks like solve similar topic
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-themes
You need only group your themes in sub-folder.

From other side `gulp.src` accepts `string` and `array` so you can pass this information from command line. 
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md

Comment: Not exactly. from the command line, I am wanting to pass `gulp build --production --theme folderName1, folderName2, folderName*`

Comment: You can additionally use package https://github.com/substack/minimist. Then when you use command **--theme** folderName1 **--theme** folderName2. Important is is to repeat name of parameter. In the minimist you have description how to pare it. This topic was discussed in https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/439